# adding 2 chars together to form one char*

Tags: c, pointers

so if I have

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';
char* combination = a + b;
```

where the result should be

```
combination = "ab"
```

how would I do that? I'm 99% sure that the "+" operator wouldn't work here, but I'm not sure what I should do instead. I am new to C, so sorry for how trivial this question is!

edit** is it possible to this without using an array? meaning without using brackets []

Comment: You'll need an array to copy them into.

Comment: What about this: `char combination[3] = {a, b, '\0'};` ?

Comment: This question is broader than it looks, because C doesn't actually have a string type the way higher-level languages (C++, Java, Python, etc) do.  It only has arrays of `char` values with a convention for where the end of the "string" is, and you have to do all of the memory management yourself.  As such, a proper answer would take, like, an entire chapter of a C textbook.  And I can't fit that into the answer box. Sorry.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using brackets? The question doesn't make much sense without knowing what you are trying to do. And it is indeed broader than it looks.

Answer (score 3):

> adding 2 chars together to form one char* ... how would I do that?

A direct way to do that since C99 is below which uses a *compound literal*.  [@haccks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52485320/adding-2-chars-together-to-form-one-char#comment91912149_52485320), [@unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485807/2410359)

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';

//                   v-------------------v--- compound literal
char* combination1 = (char[]) {a, b, '\0'};

printf("<%s>\n", combination1);
```

`combination1` is valid until the end of the block.

> I'm 99% sure that the "+" operator wouldn't work here,

OP is correct, `+`  is not the right approach.

---

> is it possible to this without using an array? meaning without using brackets []

This is a curious restrictive requirement.

Code could allocate memory and then assign.

```
char *concat2char(char a, char b) {
  char *combination = malloc(3);
  if (combination) {
    char *s = combination;
    *s++ = a;
    *s++ = b;
    *s = '\0';
  }
  return combination;
}

// Sample usage
char *combination2 = concat2char('a', 'b');
if (combination2) {
  printf("<%s>\n", combination2);
  free(combination2);  // free memory when done
}
```

---

Using a 3 member `struct` looks like an option, yet portable code does not rely in `s3` being *packed*.

```
struct {
  char a, b, n;
} s3 = {a, b, '\0' };

// Unreliable to form a string, do not use !!
char* combination3 = (char *) &s3;

printf("<%s>\n", combination);
```

Comment: That last use of struct is *so* dodgy, I'd leave it out entirely. Or at least add a static assert to check that it is really packed. And maybe use union instead of direct `(char*)` cast.

Comment: @hyde The 3rd is there, not as an example of what to use, but an example of what not to use. Hence the coded comment `do not use !!`.

Comment: @hyde, A `union` with a `char[3]` serves little even though its usually the preferred approach.  There is no alignment nor anti-aliasing problems as  code is moving to a character pointer.  Yet it is a problem due to unknown padding.  IAC, it is shown as what _not_ to do.  Yet if you think that with sufficient union and static assert it is redeemable, suggest posting such a solution.

Comment: Not disagreeing really. Union would just IMO communicate intent better. And I believe "do not use this code" <-> "do not press this big red button"... :-D At least static assert would make it safe (when it compiles).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a target array that's at least one element larger than the number of characters in the final string:

```
char str[3]; // 2 characters plus string terminator

str[0] = a;
str[1] = b;
str[2] = 0; // you'll sometimes see that written as str[2] = '\0'
```

Neither the `+` nor `=` operators are defined for string operations.  You'll have to use the `str*` library functions (`strcat`, `strcpy`, `strlen`, etc.) for string operations.

**EDIT**

In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values terminated by a 0-valued byte - the string `"hello"` is represented by the character sequence `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}` (sometimes you'll see `'\0'` instead of plain `0`).  Strings are *stored* in arrays of `char`.  String literals like `"hello"` are stored in arrays of `char` such that they are visible over the lifetime of the program, but are not meant to be modified - attempting to update the contents of a string literal results in undefined behavior (code may crash, operation may just not succeed, code may behave as expected, etc.).

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element.  So when we're dealing with strings, we're usually dealing with expressions of type `char *` - however, that does not mean that a `char *` always refers to a *string*.  It can point to a single character that isn't part of a string, or it can point to a sequence of characters that don't have a 0 terminator.

So, let's start with a string literal like `"hello"`.  It will be stored "somewhere" as the array:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|'h'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'| 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

When you write something like

```
char *str = "hello";
```

the *address* of the first element of the array that stores `"hello"` is written to *pointer* variable `str`:

```
     +---+      +---+---+---+---+---+---+
str: |   | ---> |'h'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'| 0 |
     +---+      +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

While you can read each `str[i]`, you should not write to it (technically, the behavior is undefined).  On the other hand, when you write something like:

```
char str[] = "hello";
```

`str` is created as an *array*, and the *contents* of the string literal are copied to the array:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|'h'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'| 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+

     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
str: |'h'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'| 0 |
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The array is sized based on the size of the initializer, so it will be 6 elements wide (+1 for the string terminator).  If the array is going to hold the result of a concatenation or print operation, then it will need to be large enough to hold the resulting string, plus the 0 terminator, and C arrays do not automatically grow as stuff is added to them.  So, if you want to concatenate two 3-character strings together, then the target array must be *at least* 7 elements wide:

```
char result[7];
char *foo = "foo";
char *bar = "bar";

strcpy( result, foo ); // copies contents of foo to result
strcat( result, bar ); // appends the contents of bar to result
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without using arrays? I meant to add that to my question, I will add it now.

Comment: @JohnDoe you cannot have 2 chars together without it being an array, that's what "array" means

Comment: @JohnDoe: No, you cannot.  There is no way to store or manipulate strings without using arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Just define an array, and arrange the two characters into it, then end it with a final zero-character to form a proper C string:

```
const char a = 'a';
const char b = 'b';
const char my_string[] = { a, b, '\0' };
printf("The string is '%s'\n", my_string);
```

---

In response to comments (which I don't understand, but I'm here to help, heh), here's a twisted way of writing it that does away with the brackets.

```
uint32_t memory;
char *p = (char *) &memory;
*p++ = a;
*p++ = b;
*p-- = '\0';
printf("the string is '%s'\n", --p);
```

Note: this code is **absurd**, but so is the request to not use random parts of the language you're programming in. Do not use this code for anything except reading it here and thinking "wow, that would be soo much better if I could just use braces".

Comment: is it possible to do this without using arrays? I meant to add that to my question, I will add it now.

Comment: @JohnDoe A string in C is by definition an array of characters terminated by a null byte.  No array, no string.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. Can you write this without using array notation? I know that the underlying data structure for a string is an array, but I could write char* someString = "foo", right? That would not involve the use of brackets

Comment: @JohnDoe: That assigns the *address* of the first element of the array storing the string literal `"foo"` to the *pointer* variable `someString` - that works if you don't need to modify the string contents (attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior).  However, if you want to be able to modify or extend the string, you *must* use an array to store the result.